# Read RTMP stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, rtmp, live-streaming

So I'm trying to make a flutter application where I'm going to broadcast a stream from a software (e.g. OBS) and I want to listen to that and show that broadcasted stream in my Android app. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I don't want any code or anything, but any guidance will be much appreciated.